# Problem in solving an array question . That can i avoid repeatative occurance of a number

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

## Find duplicates in an array

Given an array `a[]` of size `N` which contains elements from `0 to N-1`, you need to find all the elements occurring more than once in the given array. Return the answer in ascending order.

Complete the function duplicates() which takes array `a[]` and `n` as input as parameters and returns a list of elements that occur more than once in the given array in a sorted manner. If no such element is found, return `list containing [-1]`.

**Expected Time Complexity:** O(n).
**Expected Auxiliary Space:** O(n).

**Note:** The extra space is only for the array to be returned.
Try and perform all operations within the provided array.

**Constraints:**
1 <= N <= 105
0 <= A[i] <= N-1, for each valid i

My code:

```
class Solution {
    public static ArrayList<Integer> duplicates(int arr[], int n) {
        // code hereCollections.sort(list);
        ArrayList<Integer>
            list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            Arrays.sort(arr);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for (int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
            {
                if(arr[i]==arr[j])
                {
                    list1.add(arr[i]);
                }
            }
        }
         if(list1.isEmpty())
        {
            list1.add(-1);
        }
        return list1;
    }
}
```

**Input given:**  n = 26
**arr** = 13 9 25 1 1 0 22 13 22 20 3 8 11 25 10 3 15 11 19 20 2 4 25 14 23 14

**My output is**: 1 3 11 13 14 20 22 25 25 25
**Expected output**: 1 3 11 13 14 20 22 25

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uKhe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could only count the value when it *first* occurs in the list with a dupe following it. As you have sorted your input, you can extend the condition to this (avoiding another scan of the list):

```
if (arr[i] == arr[j] && (i == 0 || arr[i-1] < arr[i]))
```

### Remark - efficiency

Sorting has a time complexity of O(log), yet this problem can be solved with linear time complexity. One may think of using a hash set or extra array, but I guess you got this code challenge [from GeeksForGeeks](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/find-duplicates-in-an-array/1), which includes the following note:

> **Note:** The extra space is only for the array to be returned.
> Try and perform all operations within the provided array.

So introducing an extra data structure is not an option either to meet this constraint.

Try to use the unsorted input to somehow mark that a value was encountered more than once.

Here is a spoiler solution that does that:

> `class Solution {
>      public static ArrayList duplicates(int arr[], int n) {
>          ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
>          int m = n + n;
>          for (var k : arr) {
>              if (arr[k % n] < m) arr[k % n] += n;
>          }
>          for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
>              if (arr[i] >= m) list.add(i);
>          }
>          // GfG wants you to return a list with -1 when there are no dupes
>          if (list.size() == 0) list.add(-1);
>          return list;
>      }
>  }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify if the value isn't already present in the list before adding it.

```
for (int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
{
    int value = arr[i];

    if(value==arr[j] && !list1.contains(value))
    {
        list1.add(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HashMap to solve this question

```
  public static ArrayList<Integer> duplicates(int arr[], int n) {
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> dupList = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if(dupList.containsKey(arr[i])) {
            dupList.put(arr[i], dupList.get(arr[i]) + 1);
        } else {
            dupList.put(arr[i], 1);
        }
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> set : dupList.entrySet()) {
        if(set.getValue() > 1) {
            result.add(set.getKey());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be as follows, avoiding the sort which has a performance of O(N log N). The following has linear performance. And the parameter n should be superfluous.

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
    int[] arr = { 13, 9, 25, 1, 1, 0, 22, 13, 22, 20, 3, 8, 11, 25, 10, 3, 15, 11, 19, 20, 2, 4,
        25, 14, 23, 14 };

    ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(arr.length);
    boolean[] check1 = new boolean[arr.length];
    boolean[] check2 = new boolean[arr.length];
    for (int e : arr) {
        if (check1[e]) {
            check2[e] = true;
        } else {
            check1[e] = true;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < check2.length; i++) {
        if (check2[i]) {
            list1.add(i);
        }
    }
    if (list1.isEmpty()) { return List.of(-1); } 
    return list1;
}
```

Comment: just add the code to check _if list is empty then add -1 in list and return list_1 instead of printing list.  `if(list1.isEmpty())
    {
         list1.add(-1);
    }
   return list1;
    }`

Comment: @Vaishali Sharma Why? The code works on an empty array and returns an empty list, i.e. no duplicates.

Comment: It should be  `if (list1.isEmpty()) { return List.of(-1); } return list1;` {For an empty array, you're supposed to return a list containing just  `-1`)

Comment: @WJS OK. I missed that. However; the main point was to avoid the sort and get an O(N) solution. It is also better than using a HashMap which is slower than O(N).

Answer (score 0):

After seeing @trincot's link for `GeeksForGeeks` I updated my answer. There are also other constraints in terms of maximum N.
The only way I could think of doing this was to use the array values to index other values and bump each targeted value by the length of the array (this pushes those indexed values beyond the range of `0 to N-1`).

Any value which equals or exceeds twice the array length is a duplicate.

The problem was then how do continue using the array values to further index the array without throwing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. So I used the remainder function with a modulus of the array length.

```
int[] arr = {
        13,9,25,1,1,0,22,13,22,20,3,8,11,25,10,3,15,11,19,20,2,4,25,14,
        23,14
};
        
List<Integer> result = duplicates(arr);
System.out.println(result);
```

prints

```
[1, 3, 11, 13, 14, 20, 22, 25]
```

The method.

```
public static List<Integer> duplicates(int arr[]) {
    
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
   
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // only need to sum twice (also prevents overflow)
        int idx = arr[i] % arr.length;
        if (arr[idx] < 2 * arr.length) {
            arr[idx] += arr.length;
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       if (arr[i] >= 2*arr.length) {
           result.add(i);
       }
    }
    return result.isEmpty() ? List.of(-1) : result;
}
```

Note: Passing the array length is not necessary or useful.  However, it can be added back in if required.